# Web API: arguments in query string not binding to parameters

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api

Short and simple.  I have a route like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "QuickSearch",
                routeTemplate: "QuickSearch/{searchQuery}",
                defaults: new { controller = "QuickSearch", action = "Search" },
                constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new string[] { "GET" }), }
                );
```

And an action that looks like this:

```
public class QuickSearchController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public QuickSearchResponse Search(string searchQuery)
        {
        }
    }
```

If I call `http://localhost:4096/QuickSearch/SearchMe`, then "SearchMe" gets bound to the searchQuery parameter, and the Search method is invoked successfully.

If, however, I call `http://localhost:4096/QuickSearch/?searchQuery=SearchMe` then I receive a 404 message saying that the "Requested URL: /QuickSearch" cannot be found.

I thought the above URLs would be equivilent?  Why doesn't it work when I use a query string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add searchQuery as an optional parameter you should be able to hit the controller action using the querystring as well:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "QuickSearch",
    routeTemplate: "QuickSearch/{searchQuery}",
    defaults: new { controller = "QuickSearch", action = "Search", searchQuery = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new string[] { "GET" }), }
    );
```

Comment: Good call, this works. It doesn't necessarily make sense to me, as I want the searchQuery parameter to be mandatory, rather than option, but I can check it in the controller method, in any case.